# Replacing a string item in a list and saving it (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to select a sub-item in a list where each list item is a different paragraph, for example:

```r
> psw_list$p1 

[1] "For"          "more"         "than"         "five"         "years,"       "William"      "Sencion"     
 [8] "did"          "the"          "same"         "task"         "over"         "and"          "over."       
[15] "He"           "signed"       "onto"         "the"          "New"          "York"         "City’s"      
[22] "housing"      "lottery"      "site"         "and"          "applied"      "for"          "one"         
[29] "of"           "the"          "city’s"       "highly"       "coveted,"     "below-market" "apartments." 
[36] "Each"         "time,"        "he"           "got"          "the"          "same"         "response:"   
[43] "silence."
```

This paragraph is the first item in the list, and I'd like to go through it and select one word to change, however when I use this code to try and do that, it doesn't actually replace it in the list:

```r
str_replace(psw_list$p1[5], psw_list$p1[5], 'coersion')
```

I've tried this with the sub() and gsub() functions as well and neither change the word in the list, they just return the 'substituted' word, but when I print the first list item it is exactly the same. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste your raw data in the question as `dput(psw_list$p1)`?

Comment: you need to actually assign the value `psw_list$p1[5] <- str_replace(psw_list$p1[5], psw_list$p1[5], 'coersion')`